# Why a variable function can be called from a array in php?

Tags: php

I am reading the documentation of php about [Variable functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)

I don't understand the example 4 below.

How come the first and second `$func();` can call the function `bar()` and `baz()`. The `$func` is a `array`.

Maybe it is a silly question. Thanks.

```php
<?php
class Foo
{
    static function bar()
    {
        echo "bar\n";
    }
    function baz()
    {
        echo "baz\n";
    }
}

$func = array("Foo", "bar");
$func(); // prints "bar"
$func = array(new Foo, "baz");
$func(); // prints "baz"
$func = "Foo::bar";
$func(); // prints "bar"
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation of [callables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) - if an array is used, the first element references the class name to be used, the second element references the method name to be called. This means, the two last lines are equal:

```php
$func = array("Foo", "bar");

$func(); // prints "bar"
Foo::bar(); // also prints "bar"
```

Comment: Thanks, it would be better if the ```callables``` are mentioned in the vairable functions example as a reference. Also, the callables documentation doesn't have examples like ```$func()```.